java.io.FileNotFoundException using Square Wire to load proto schema
I got an exception when using SchemaLoader to load a proto file.

Here is the detailed exception stack trace:


java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.1.2.jar (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:344) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:259) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:213) ~[na:na]
at okio.JvmSystemFileSystem.openReadOnly(JvmSystemFileSystem.kt:83) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ZipFilesKt.openZip(ZipFiles.kt:66) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.toJarRoot(ResourceFileSystem.kt:196) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.toClasspathRoots(ResourceFileSystem.kt:179) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.access$toClasspathRoots(ResourceFileSystem.kt:45) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem$roots$2.invoke(ResourceFileSystem.kt:50) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem$roots$2.invoke(ResourceFileSystem.kt:50) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/:1.8.22-release-407(1.8.22)]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.getRoots(ResourceFileSystem.kt:50) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.(ResourceFileSystem.kt:54) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.internal.ResourceFileSystem.(ResourceFileSystem.kt:45) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.Okio__JvmOkioKt.asResourceFileSystem(JvmOkio.kt:227) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at okio.Okio.asResourceFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[okio-jvm-3.9.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.CoreLoader.resourceFileSystem_delegate$lambda$0(CoreLoader.kt:34) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/:1.8.22-release-407(1.8.22)]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.CoreLoader.getResourceFileSystem(CoreLoader.kt:33) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.CoreLoader.load(CoreLoader.kt:39) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.internal.CommonSchemaLoader.load(CommonSchemaLoader.kt:150) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.Linker.getFileLinker$wire_schema(Linker.kt:95) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.Linker.link(Linker.kt:117) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.internal.CommonSchemaLoader.loadSchema(CommonSchemaLoader.kt:105) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.squareup.wire.schema.SchemaLoader.loadSchema(SchemaLoader.kt:77) ~[wire-schema-jvm-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.fastgrpc.starter.services.ProtobufImportServiceImpl.loadProtoSchema(ProtobufImportServiceImpl.java:229) ~[fastgrpc-starter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.fastgrpc.starter.services.ProtobufImportServiceImpl.getProtobufSchemaFromContent(ProtobufImportServiceImpl.java:114) ~[fastgrpc-starter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.fastgrpc.starter.services.ProtobufImportServiceImpl.handle(ProtobufImportServiceImpl.java:75) ~[fastgrpc-starter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.ext.components.handler.ImportFileEventHandler.handle(ImportFileEventHandler.java:76) ~[kernelsoft-modeling-ext-components-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.ext.components.editingcontext.KsEditingContextEventProcessor.handleInput(KsEditingContextEventProcessor.java:396) ~[kernelsoft-modeling-ext-components-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.ext.components.editingcontext.KsEditingContextEventProcessor.doHandle(KsEditingContextEventProcessor.java:335) ~[kernelsoft-modeling-ext-components-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at com.kernelsoft.modeling.ext.components.editingcontext.KsEditingContextEventProcessor.lambda$handle$2(KsEditingContextEventProcessor.java:266) ~[kernelsoft-modeling-ext-components-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
at org.eclipse.sirius.components.web.concurrent.DelegatingRequestContextRunnable.run(DelegatingRequestContextRunnable.java:40) ~[sirius-components-web-2024.3.3.jar!/:2024.3.3]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]


And here is my current method to load proto schema:

private Schema loadProtoSchema(File tempProtoDir, File tempProtoFile) {
    try {
        // Create a file system instance using okio file system
        //  FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM;
        //
        //  Create a SchemaLoader instance
        //  SchemaLoader schemaLoader = new SchemaLoader(fileSystem);

        // Use the default nio FileSystem
        java.nio.file.FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();

        // Create a SchemaLoader
        SchemaLoader schemaLoader = new SchemaLoader(fileSystem);

        // Define the source path (directory containing proto files)
        List<Location> sourcePaths =
            Collections.singletonList(Location.get(tempProtoDir.getAbsolutePath()));

        // If a specific proto file is provided, use it as protoPaths for single proto file handling
        List<Location> protoPaths = tempProtoFile != null
            ? Collections.singletonList(Location.get(tempProtoFile.getAbsolutePath()))
            : Collections.emptyList();

        // Initialize the SchemaLoader with source paths and proto paths
        schemaLoader.initRoots(sourcePaths, protoPaths);

        // Load and return the schema
        return schemaLoader.loadSchema();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("Error loading proto schema", exception);
        return null;
    }
}

I have tried two constructors of SchemaLoader which use ikio filesystem and nio filesystem respectively. This error occurred but in both ways.

Here is my working scenario:
My application is a maven based spring boot project, which will be packaged into a jar file by deployment. While debugging in workspace there was no problem to load schema of proto files. Only after deployment when running through the jar file, this error occurred. I am using Square Wire 5.1.0 version, here are the pom dependencies:


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.wire</groupId>
    <artifactId>wire-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.wire</groupId>
    <artifactId>wire-schema-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Kotlin dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>


I didn't find a way to solve it. Can someone please help me to address this problem? Thanks.
